# Leaflet Polygon issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I created polygon with leaflet, i am very sure that my  coordinates are correct, i have 2 areas, when i run per area the map is correct, but when i join these areas into one page, map shows incorrect, please help,

[image: 1st map]

[image: 2nd Map]

[image: Joined Map]

```html
   <script>
    var map    = L.map('map').setView([-8.096872,112.1459743], 14);
var poli_1 = [["-8.09897779904717","112.14180430942015"],["-8.099084017318027","112.14195451312499"],["-8.098860958916857","112.14218518310027"],["-8.098643211310808","112.14239439540343"],["-8.09858479120135","112.14249095492796"],["-8.09854298308181","112.14252045922713"],["-8.098479252037022","112.14252314143614"],["-8.09840755459957","112.14254728131728"],["-8.09838365545092","112.14261433654265"],["-8.098359756300846","112.14272430711226"],["-8.098322579842367","112.14280477338271"],["-8.098293369765434","112.1429120617433"],["-8.098258848762683","112.14293888383345"],["-8.098213705908488","112.1429657059236"],["-8.09817918489892","112.14297911696868"],["-8.098134042035781","112.1429844813867"],["-8.098099654784006","112.14299628268468"],["-8.098030612742347","112.14299360047566"],["-8.097988125326221","112.14299091826665"],["-8.097935016049735","112.14299091826665"],["-8.097826142011076","112.14299091826665"],["-8.097802242827925","112.14295604954945"],["-8.09776241085283","112.14292386304128"],["-8.09773054526993","112.14289435874211"],["-8.097680091425175","112.14286217223393"],["-8.097658847699176","112.14286217223393"],["-8.097613704777705","112.14287826548802"],["-8.09754466265273","112.14287558327901"],["-8.097557796001265","112.14283436536789"],["-8.097461547728516","112.14278975259053"],["-8.097324959221128","112.14264827430445"],["-8.09719484126706","112.14250075280863"],["-8.09714173188596","112.14234518468577"],["-8.097123143600927","112.1420984214564"],["-8.097067378740666","112.1418838447352"],["-8.09689742864273","112.14156197965342"],["-8.096445356223212","112.1406644982846"],["-8.096241253451407","112.1402108075272"],["-8.096850698600928","112.13999765956875"],["-8.097132124121744","112.13992064439971"],["-8.097437475813408","112.1398123993808"],["-8.097637949962461","112.13975291245329"],["-8.097791296302026","112.13970171131744"],["-8.097997751858369","112.13962905250948"],["-8.09852495219415","112.14079714723526"],["-8.098740753849725","112.14132218599984"]];
    var polygon = L.polygon(poli_1, {color: 'red'}).addTo(map);



var poli_2 = [["-8.09827779904717","112.14180430942015"],["-8.099084017318027","112.14195451312499"],["-8.098860958916857","112.14218518310027"],["-8.098643211310808","112.12239439540343"],["-8.09858479120135","112.14249095492796"],["-8.09854298308181","112.14252045922713"],["-8.098479252037022","112.14252314143614"],["-8.09840755459957","112.14254728131728"],["-8.09838365545092","112.14261433654265"],["-8.098359756300846","112.14272430711226"],["-8.098322579842367","112.14280477338271"],["-8.098293369765434","112.1429120617433"],["-8.098258848762683","112.14293888383345"],["-8.098213705908488","112.1429657059236"],["-8.09817918489892","112.14297911696868"],["-8.098134042035781","112.1429844813867"],["-8.098099654784006","112.14299628268468"],["-8.098030612742347","112.14299360047566"],["-8.097988125326221","112.14299091826665"],["-8.097935016049735","112.14299091826665"],["-8.097826142011076","112.14299091826665"],["-8.097802242827925","112.14295604954945"],["-8.09776241085283","112.14292386304128"],["-8.09773054526993","112.14289435874211"],["-8.097680091425175","112.14286217223393"],["-8.097658847699176","112.14286217223393"],["-8.097613704777705","112.14287826548802"],["-8.09754466265273","112.14287558327901"],["-8.097557796001265","112.14283436536789"],["-8.097461547728516","112.14278975259053"],["-8.097324959221128","112.14264827430445"],["-8.09719484126706","112.14250075280863"],["-8.09714173188596","112.14234518468577"],["-8.097123143600927","112.1420984214564"],["-8.097067378740666","112.1418838447352"],["-8.09689742864273","112.14156197965342"],["-8.096445356223212","112.1406644982846"],["-8.096241253451407","112.1402108075272"],["-8.096850698600928","112.13999765956875"],["-8.097132124121744","112.13992064439971"],["-8.097437475813408","112.1398123993808"],["-8.097637949962461","112.13975291245329"],["-8.097791296302026","112.13970171131744"],["-8.097997751858369","112.13962905250948"],["-8.09852495219415","112.14079714723526"],["-8.098740753849725","112.14132218599984"]];
    var polygon = L.polygon(poli_2, {color: 'yellow'}).addTo(map);

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
              }).addTo(map);



              L.marker([-8.096872,112.1459743]).addTo(map)
               .bindPopup('Test Map')
               .openPopup();
    </script>
```

Comment: Hmm. Did you change your code after submitting the pictures? Anyway, running the example above works fine. Coordinates bit weird on the second polygon, but it's still displaying correctly. Either one, or both. Still correct:
https://jsfiddle.net/zvqsbr02/8/

Comment: I have done it, i got error on my code, thanks for helping